# Python editor in RCP application

Tags: python, eclipse-rcp, pydev, rcp

I am creating an RCP applictaion which needs python editor along with it. From other posts i found pydev is the best opion. I have the pydev plugin added in my rcp application. But how do i open a python editor? How to use pydev plugin in rcp application?

Comment: Does your RCP have a workspace like the Eclipse IDE (so you can use `IWorkbench` and the like)?

Comment: Yes the RCP has the workspace like the Eclipse IDE. I have a pydev jar added to dropins folder. I am not sure of how to enable\activate the pydev plugin. Please let me know how to do that with IWorkbench. Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

This works with PyDev 2.7 and Eclipse Indigo.

I added the `org.pydev` into `plugin.xml`.

Implement a button (ex: Go to Pydev Perspective, and in the handler open the Pydev Perspective).

```
ViewUtility.OpenPerspective("org.python.pydev.ui.PythonPerspective");
```